# A question about invertible matrices

Tags: matrices

A square matrix $A$ over the reals  is said to be  invertible in practice if there exists a matrix $B$ of the same size s. t. all the  entries  of $AB$ differ from  the corresponding entries of the identity matrix $E$ less than or equal to $10^{-10}$. Does there exist invertible in practice marix which is not invertible?

Comment: If this definition corresponds to how things are done in practice, however, then the set of matrices that are invertible in practice should be a strict subset of the invertible matrices.

Comment: @angryavian if that were the case, then $A$ would be invertible in practice if and only if it were invertible

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom: Why do you think so?

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom: How about $ n>10^{10}$?

Comment: (Retyped): Let $\|\cdot\|$ be the column-sum (or row-sum) norm.  Assume we're talking about $n \times n$ matrices. Let $M$ be a matrix such that $|M_{ij} - I_{ij}| \leq 10^{-10}$.  Then $\|M - I\| \leq n/{10^{10}}$.  It follows that $\sigma(M) \subset [1-n/{10^{10}},1+n/{10^{10}}]$.  It follows that $M$ must be invertible as long as $n  < 10^{10}$.

Comment: For $n \geq 10^{10}$, we can get an non-invertible matrix that is invertible in practice by subtracting $10^{-10}$ from each entry of the identity matrix.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom: Can you elaborate your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, if that's really interesting to you.  I would remind you, however, that in discussing $10^{10}\times 10^{10}$-sized matrices, we have deviated drastically from practice.  Could you elaborate on the motivation for this definition and this question?

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom: Please convert your comment to your answer. I would like my question was rightly answered. Of course, $10^{10}$ is too big, the one may be replaced by $10^4$, say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of $n \times n$ matrices that are "invertible in practice" is exactly the set of $n \times n$ matrices that are invertible, as long as $n < 10^{10}$.

For $n \geq 10^{10}$, invertible matrices are invertible in practice, but not the other way around. For a counterexample, consider the matrix given by
$$
A_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
1 - 1/n & i=j\\
-1/n & i \neq j
\end{cases}
$$
Noting that the row sums of $A$ are all zero, we may conclude that $A$ is not invertible.  Nevertheless, it is "invertible in practice".

Comment: +1: Nice. We must have $\|A-I\|  \ge 1$ for any sub-multiplicative norm.

Comment: (My point was that it is curious how dimension plays into sub-multiplicative matrix norms.)

Comment: @copper.hat thank you! And agreed; it's one of the many counter-intuitive things about $n$-dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, but practically, no.

Technical answer:

Consider the $n\times n$ matrix

$$M = \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}1 & x & x & \ldots & x\\x & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\x & 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0\\ \vdots &  & & \ddots & \\ x & 0 & 0 &\ldots & 1\end{array}\right].$$

By row-reduction the determinant of this matrix is $1 - (n-1)x^2$ and in particular, $M$ is singular when $x = \sqrt{1/(n-1)}$. You can make $x$ arbitrary small (in particular, less than $10^{-10}$) by making $n$ arbitrary large; and then if $AB = M$, at least one of $A$ or $B^T$ is singular while being "practically invertible."

---

Practical answer: suppose your matrix is $n\times n$, where $n < 10^{10}$. Then any matrix $M$ that is close to the identity matrix, in the sense you describe, is strictly diagonally dominant and hence nonsingular. Therefore any $A, B$ with $AB=M$ are both nonsingular as well.

Comment: @ user7530: +1. The question arises: does there exist a counterexample of  a different kind?